# How to send multiple JSON data from CSV file in single HTTP request in JMETER tool

Tags: json, http, jmeter, request

my JSON structure is:

```
        {
        "ID": "1",

        "DATE": "2",

        "VILLA": [{
                            "HSENO":"${HSENO}",
                            "STREETNO": "${STREETNO}",
                            "CITY": "${CITY}",
                            "STATE": "${STATE}",

                 }],
        "FLATS": []
        }
```

My Excel Have 1000 datas (1000 HSENO, 1000 STREETNO, 1000 CITY, 1000 STATE) for Villa's.
In Jmeter how can I read these 1000 datas & make HTTP SINGLE request.

I have referred beanshell script but still couldn't succeed.

PLease help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming that you have `test.csv` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation which looks like:

   ```
   house1,street1,city1,state1
   house2,street2,city2,state2
   house3,street3,city3,state3
   ```
2. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request you want to parameterize
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

   @groovy.transform.Immutable
   class VILLA {
       String HSENO
       String STREETNO
       String CITY
       String STATE
   }

   def villas = new File("test.csv")
           .readLines()
           .collect { line ->
               new VILLA(line.split(",")[0], line.split(",")[1], line.split(",")[2], line.split(",")[3]) }

   builder(
           ID:1,
           DATE: 2,
           VILLA: villas.collect(),
           FLATS:[]
   )
   log.info(builder.toPrettyString())
   vars.put("payload", builder.toPrettyString())
   ```

You should see generated request body in *jmeter.log* file and should be able to use `${payload}` JMeter Variable where required to pass the generated data.

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)

Comment: Genius !! Thanks for the extended support.

Comment: I have defined ${payload} in the body data of HTTP request, But there i can see the payload within square bracelets  [].    how to eliminate the square bracelets . pls suggest.